# Make less variables accessible from javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, less

I have a less file colours which defines looks like the following:

```
@black:                 #000;
@greyDarker:            #222;
...etc
```

And want to be able to access these from within javascript, so for example:

```
$('body').style('color', 'window.colours.black') // or however I assign them
```

would work.

Since Less is getting compiled server-side the usual options wouldn't work.

I've started going ahead and writing a grunt task to generate a js file from these less rules however this seems like an inefficient / hacky way to go about it.

Any suggestions on a better approach or tools that could help

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you? If so, please accept.

Comment: Do you have any results worth mentioning from your grunt task? I am currently thinking about the same issue - making less variables (mainly resolution-specific breakpoints) known in JS. In my case, I'd prefer a build task, grunt, gulp or something which I can integrate into our project build

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could put some special definitions in your CSS to pass through the definitions. These would only be used to pass the variables and nothing else. You'd need to come up with some convention, here I've used div.less-rule-{rule-name}

For example.

```
div.less-rule-black {
    background-color: @black;
}
div.less-rule-grey-darker {
    background-color: @greyDarker;
}
```

You could then pick these up using the JavaScript API for accessing stylesheets. You could put this in a utility class somewhere. This only needs to be done once when all the stylesheets are loaded.

```
var rules, rule, i, n, j, m, key;
var lessRules = [];
for (i = 0, n = document.styleSheets.length; i < n; i++) {
    rules = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules; 
    for (j = 0, m = rules.length; j < m; j++) {
        rule = rules[j];
        if (rules[j].selectorText.indexOf('less-rule') !== -1) {
           key = /div.less-rule-(.*)/.exec(rules[j].selectorText)[1];
           lessRules[key] = rule.style['background-color']; 
        }
    }
}
```

You can then access the variables by using the key in the hash.

```
console.log(lessRules['black']);
console.log(lessRules['grey-darker']);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use css variables Like

```js
let StyleVars = document.querySelector(':root');
// Create a function for getting a variable value
function GetStyleVars(Variable = "--color" ) {
  // Get the styles (properties and values) for the root
    var Style = getComputedStyle(StyleVars);
    return(Style.getPropertyValue(Variable));
}
// Create a function for setting a variable value
function ChangeVariableValue(Value,Variable = "--color") {
  // Set the value of variable to another Value
  StyleVars.style.setProperty(Variable, Value);
}


document.getElementById("A").onclick = function(){
ChangeVariableValue('red');
}



document.getElementById("B").onclick = function(){
ChangeVariableValue('green');
}


document.getElementById("C").onclick = function(){
ChangeVariableValue('black');
}


document.getElementById("D").onclick = function(){
alert(GetStyleVars());
}
```

```css
:root{
 --color : #fff;
}
button{
border :2px solid var(--color);
}
```

```html
<button id="A">Red</button>
<br>
<button id="B">Green</button>
<br>
<button id="C">Black</button>
<br>
<button id="D">Alert Value</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

First add a rule using the LESS variable to your CSS.
Then create a dummy element with that class, and examine its `getComputedStyle` color:

```js
function getLessVariableValue(variable) {
    var elt = document.createElement('div');
    elt.className = variable+"-variable";
    elt.style.display= "none";        // ensure element is not visible
    document.body.appendChild(elt);   // elt must be in DOM to compute styles
    var result = window.getComputedStyle(elt).fontFamily;
    document.body.removeChild(elt);
    return result;
}

document.writeln(getLessVariableValue('purple'))
```

```css
/* replace "purple" below with '@purple' etc. */
.purple-variable { font-family: purple; }
```

We use `font-family` because it can take any arbitrary string as its value.

Alternatively, you could look through the style rules for the one with `.purple-variable` as a selector, as @Adam suggests in his answer. To me that seems a bit more involved.

However, this seems like a lot of work to go to, to accomplish--what? There may be better ways to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach each color to a class name in your style rules and then add a particular class to your object to trigger the setting of the desired color.  The class names would be defined in your CSS styles and then you just refer to them by string name in your javascript.

CSS:

```
.black {color: #000;}
.greyDarker {color: #222;}
```

Javascript:

```
$('body').addClass('black');
```

---

You can also use the CSS color names built into the browser:

```
$('body').css('color', 'black');
```

Here's a list of color names built in: http://www.crockford.com/wrrrld/color.html and http://www.cssportal.com/css3-color-names/,

---

Other than something like this, if you want programmatic access to symbolic names for colors, then you will need to generate your own Javascript definitions for the names and include that in your javascript where you can use those symbols.

Comment: Solid suggestion, however still doesn't address using the colour different rules, i.e. background, border, etc.
I understand this sort of thing is exactly what css classes are intended for, just want to avoid writing the same things too often.

Comment: @ioseph - I've added a couple other options, but this is it.  What you're asking for doesn't exist without either using the color names already built into the browse or defining your own symbols.

Comment: I'd rather do it in opposite: define variables in javascript code (e.g some JSON stuff) and supply those to Less compiler via `globalVars`/`modifyVars` (there're no specific compiler options to import JSON but this is doable via `grunt` tasks).

Comment: @seven-phases-max - do you really have to make up your own color names/values rather than use the established named?

Comment: @jfriend00 (Sorry I guess I should initially add my comment to the Q and not to your A). Yes, if it's just about some styling then your approach is the way to go (and original OP desire looks strange) but if it's really about some generic "I need some variables values shared in my Less code and in my JavaScript code" then...